# NServiceBus Version 7.1.x configrution in asp.net core 3.0 best way

Tags: api, nservicebus, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using NServiceBus as middelware for an asp.net core 3.0 API. I already configured the service in my API using NServiceBus version 7.2 because the documentation for that on the website of particular is amazing. Saddly I have a probleem because i got a licence for an older version of NServiceBus versions until version 7.1.x are valid. 
my question is: is there a recomendition for configuring NServiceBus in asp.net core using Versions 7.1.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use an external container and configure the endpoint to use it. Take a look at the sample available in the README of the [`MSDependencyInjection`](https://github.com/twenzel/NServiceBus.MSDependencyInjection) container.

The same thing can be achieved, with very similar code using one of the supported IoC container: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/dependency-injection/#internally-managed-mode-using-a-third-party-container